# Change Google Places Autocomplete Language without reloading

Tags: google-maps-api-3, translation

It's easy enough to specify a language in Google Places Autocomplete

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places**&language=en**"></script>
```

That's well and good.  But I need the ability to change the language on the fly without reloading the page.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by dynamically reloading the google library each time you want to switch the language. It will result in reloading the entire map, but not the page.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-maps-api/DGhG-D37Glw

This discussion has a sample on how to do it(http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dynamicloading/scriptappend_hl.html). Basically you append the new language appropriate library to the page, and reload your map. The post is a little out of date, but I think the concept is solid. I suspect you may have to new up another autocomplete instance each time you switch languages as well.